# Integrating a Complex Exponential Function

Tags: integration, complex-analysis

Suppose $w=\exp(2i\pi/3)$.  How would I go about integrating

$$\int\frac{3dx}{e^x+e^{wx}+e^{w^2x}}$$

Is there a transformation i can use?  This is an entire function; there is no $x$ that will produce poles.  If I said that

$$\frac{3}{e^x+e^{wx}+e^{w^2x}}=\sum_{n=0}^\infty A_{3n}\frac{x^{3n}}{(3n)!}$$

Then can't I say that

$$\int\frac{3dx}{e^x+e^{wx}+e^{w^2x}}=\int \sum_{n=0}^\infty A_{3n}\frac{x^{3n}}{(3n)!}=\sum_{n=0}^\infty A_{3n}\int\frac{x^{3n}}{(3n)!}=\sum_{n=0}^\infty A_{3n}\frac{x^{3n+1}}{(3n+1)!}$$

But this wont give me information regarding the generating function I need.  Any suggestions?

Comment: The function is not entire.  For example, there is a pole at approximately $x=2.72+i 4.71$.

Comment: Interesting.  I thought it was.....

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Well, I bet you are aware of the identity:
$$\frac{e^x+e^{\omega x}+e^{\omega^2 x}}{3}=\sum_{n\geq 0}\frac{x^{3n}}{(3n)!}\tag{1}$$
hence by assuming
$$ \frac{3}{e^{x}+e^{\omega x}+e^{\omega^2 x}}=\sum_{n\geq 0}A_{3n} \frac{x^{3n}}{(3n)!} \tag{2}$$
and considering the Cauchy product of $(1)$ and $(2)$ we get $A_0=1$ and
$$ \sum_{n=0}^{m}\binom{3m}{3n}A_{3n} = 0,\tag{3}$$
so our coefficients can be computed by recursion and they give a generalization of [Bernoulli numbers](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/BernoulliNumber.html). Continuing the analogy, since integrals like $\int_{0}^{+\infty}\frac{dx}{\cosh x}\,dx$ and $\int_{0}^{+\infty}\frac{x^k\,dx}{\sinh x}\,dx$ are related with the Riemann $\zeta$ function, my bet is that your integral is related with another $\zeta$-function, the [Epstein zeta function](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/EpsteinZetaFunction.html).

Comment: Yes, I appreciate that and have done some work with generalized Bernoulli numbers and polynomials.  But the integral is really my concern.  The method I used above is only because I've studied the function.  I really am interested in getting the generating function.

Comment: @Eleven-Eleven: continuing the analogy, since integrals like $\int_{0}^{+\infty}\frac{dx}{\cosh x}\,dx$ and $\int_{0}^{+\infty}\frac{x^k\,dx}{\sinh x}\,dx$ are related with the Riemann $\zeta$ function, my bet is that your integral is related with another $\zeta$-function, the Epstein zeta function: http://mathworld.wolfram.com/EpsteinZetaFunction.html

Comment: This looks like an interesting lead.  My thanks!!